# ConstraintLayout: How to align Two TextViews vertically center

Tags: android, kotlin

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.CardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/mtrl_card_spacing"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/mtrl_card_spacing"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/mtrl_card_spacing"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/mtrl_card_spacing"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="84dp">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_logo_home_team"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/match_item_team_logo"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/match_item_team_logo"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/unit_dp_10"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/unit_dp_10"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/unit_dp_10"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/unit_dp_10"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_player_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/unit_sp_12"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/unit_sp_10"
                app:fontFamily="@font/avenir_next_bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/iv_logo_home_team"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_player_role"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/unit_sp_12"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/unit_sp_12"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="@dimen/unit_sp_10"
                app:fontFamily="@font/avenir_next_bold"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/iv_logo_home_team"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_player_name"
                tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

Design View:

[image: Image Added]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Constrain `tv_player_name` top to `iv_logo_home_team` top, constrain `tv_player_role` bottom to `iv_logo_home_team` bottom, set vertical chain style to `packed`. Also constrain `tv_player_name` and `tv_player_role` to each other vertically (create a chain). In other words:

```xml
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
  android:id="@+id/tv_player_name"
  ...
  app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
  app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/iv_logo_home_team"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv_logo_home_team"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_player_role" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
  android:id="@+id/tv_player_role"
  ...
  app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/iv_logo_home_team"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_player_name"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_logo_home_team" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For your view `tv_player_name` replace this `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`
 attribute to `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_player_role"`, and for view `tv_player_role` add this attribute `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`.

It will look like this.

[image]

Code

```
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_player_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_player_role"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/iv_logo_home_team"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_player_role"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/iv_logo_home_team"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_player_name"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem" />
```

If you want to make it center like this.

[image]

Then add this attribute `app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"` for both views.

Code

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_player_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tv_player_role"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/iv_logo_home_team"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_player_role"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/iv_logo_home_team"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_player_name"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem" />
```